# How to take screenshot of entire screen outside of your FLUTTER DESKTOP app(mostly for Windows OS)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm new to flutter. Now I am able to take screenshot for my entire desktop app screen using Screenshot package & storing that image to local storage.

But my requirement is to capture the screenshot of entire screen of the window, like if 2 applications are opened(1 Flutter + 1 any other app e.g. browser) in 1 screen, then we can able to take whole screen's screenshot not only flutter app.

Please help me on how to take entire window's screenshot in Windows OS desktop app?
If it's not possible directly from Flutter, then how to achieve this by implementing some native code with Flutter?

Answer (score 3):

check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_capturer) completely working as expected

```
 bool _isAccessAllowed = false;

  CapturedData? _lastCapturedData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  void _init() async {
    _isAccessAllowed = await ScreenCapturer.instance.isAccessAllowed();
  }

  void _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode mode) async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String imageName =
        'Screenshot-${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
    String imagePath =
        '${directory.path}/screen_capturer_example/Screenshots/$imageName';
    _lastCapturedData = await ScreenCapturer.instance.capture(
      mode: mode,
      imagePath: imagePath,
      silent: true,
    );
    if (_lastCapturedData != null) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      // print(_lastCapturedData!.toJson());
    } else {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('User canceled capture');
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferenceList(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (Platform.isMacOS)
          PreferenceListSection(
            children: [
              PreferenceListItem(
                title: const Text('isAccessAllowed'),
                accessoryView: Text('$_isAccessAllowed'),
                onTap: () async {
                  bool allowed =
                  await ScreenCapturer.instance.isAccessAllowed();
                  BotToast.showText(text: 'allowed: $allowed');
                  setState(() {
                    _isAccessAllowed = allowed;
                  });
                },
              ),
              PreferenceListItem(
                title: const Text('requestAccess'),
                onTap: () async {
                  await ScreenCapturer.instance.requestAccess();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        PreferenceListSection(
          title: const Text('METHODS'),
          children: [
            PreferenceListItem(
              title: const Text('capture'),
              accessoryView: Row(children: [
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Text('region'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode.region);
                  },
                ),
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Text('screen'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode.screen);
                  },
                ),
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Text('window'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode.window);
                  },
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (_lastCapturedData != null && _lastCapturedData?.imagePath != null)
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            child: Image.file(
              File(_lastCapturedData!.imagePath!),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

// screen shot taken by the App.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might try using this package: [screen_capturer](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_capturer). It works on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

From the docs:
Example of usage:

```
import 'package:screen_capturer/screen_capturer.dart';

CapturedData? capturedData = await screenCapturer.capture(
  mode: CaptureMode.screen, // screen, window
  imagePath: '<path>',
);
```

CaptureMode.screen is to capture the entire screen.

The screenshot package which you mention is only for taking screenshots for widgets of your app not of whole screen.